# reading capacitance on digital meter

Tags: capacitor, multimeter, capacitance

So I bought this digital meter from radioshack because it tests capacitance. I have several caps on a TV power board, most of which are 47uf and 470uf with various voltages.

when I check with the meter, it gives me readings like 4.851 with no symbol, so I cant set or tell which scale it's on. SOME caps are coming up low, like 2.556 on a 470uf cap. Those caps are not bulged at all, but are they bad? Am I reading them wrong?

Comment: Are you reading them in circuit? That will affect the reading.

Answer (score 1):

What you are reading is the capacitance of the net to Gnd. Not that capacitors capacitance.  In order to do that, you will need to disconnect the capacitors terminal and then check it.  Lifting only one side should be fine.

Comment: This is good to know. Ill have to disconnect them all; they're hard soldered on

Answer (score 0):

The capacitor values you mention are likely to be electrolytic types that are polarised i.e. have terminals marked +/- or red/black. Such capacitors can show low capacitance or have excessive leakage resistance if there is no DC polarising voltage of the expected polarity. Most important, the digital tester should have been provided with a specification or user guide that explains the range of capacitors that it can measure. As already noted, at least one end of the capacitor to be measured must be disconnected from the circuit it is normally used in.